# How can I set a Property using NHibernate Mapping column using some crtieria

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to specify a column of my domain object which will be of Type Product lets say.  Instead of this being a normal relationhip like one to one for example or one to many etc... I want this property to be a product, but also it is the most sold product.

So if I have an Object called ProductCategory

```
public class ProductCategory{
    public virtual Product BestSellingProduct{get;set;}
}
```

So my question is how can I integrate this logic into the mapping file for ProductCategory.  I am not sure how the formule attribute of the property element could be used to return an object from the sql.  Can HQL be used?

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't make BestSellingProduct a property on ProductCategory - I mean I would imagine a ProductCatalog that can answere to : get me the bestselling product for a category .

If you **really** want to use the property then you could do what section 13.4 says should be possible : [Custom SQL for loading - nhibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Comment: Cheers that looks like the ticket!! :-)

Comment: I'm glad it's what you need, but again - i'd advise against it. Best of luck